# Generating a for loop that will make plots and give them the right title

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-analysis

The problem is in for loop. It seems that it does not pick up the title for every plot that is generated with AAstat function.

```
prot_seq <- read.fasta("FGF2-ortholog-proteins", seqtype = "AA" )       
anns <- (getAnnot(prot_seq))
org_names <- c("Homo sapiens", "Pan troglodytes", "Gallus gallus", "Rattus norvegicus", "Mus musculus", "Canis lupus familiaris")
all_seq <- getSequence(prot_seq)
for (i in all_seq) {
  AAstat(i)
  title(org_names[i])
}
```

The output should be different plots of different amino acid sequences with the right title above (the name of the organism). But, all I get is a plot without the title.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping through `all_seq` with:

```
for (i in all_seq) {
```

the values of `i` will be the sequences in `all_seq`, not a numerical index you can use to subset `org_names`.

To run the loop the way you want, you should loop with `seq_along` to get numerical indexes, then use them to subset `all_seq` in the loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(all_seq)) {
      AAstat(all_seq[i])
      title(org_names[i])
}
```